# Adding strings to ArrayList from strings.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, arrays, string

I have been parsing html to get the title of a specific link. I am able to add this string to the string array but I want to add a string from a string array which resides in my strings.xml resource.

```
int i = 1;
String time = null;
for (Element title : rels) {
    time = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.times)[i];
    titleArray.add(time + title.attr("title"));
    i++;
}
```

Here is my strings resource:

```
<string-array name="times">
    <item name="1">12:00 am</item>
    <item name="2">12:30 am</item>
    <item name="3">1:00 am</item>
    <item name="4">1:30 am</item>
    <item name="5">2:00 am</item>
</string-array>
```

I'm getting this error in LogCat:

```
04-06 01:44:08.837: E/AndroidRuntime(30938): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=48; index=48
```

I have 48 strings in this string array, which is exactly the same number of strings I'm parsing from the html.  I'm not sure why my app is force closing.  Does anyone know?

Comment: have you tried starting with int i = 0; ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array indices start at 0 not 1. Change `i` to start at `0`:

```
int i = 0;
```

Comment: I did try that, but my array starts at 1.  Should I change the item names in the array to begin at 0?

Comment: @Josh Your array starts at 0. Also, the "name" attribute on "item" doesn't do anything. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray (note that "item" has no attributes).

Comment: I realize now that the name attribute was superfluous. Trying to teach myself java and I don't realize things like all string arrays have their own indices (which begin at 0).  Thank you for the comment and the link.  It was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

your loop should start from 0 index

```
    int i = 0;
    String time = null;
    for (Element title : rels) {
        time = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.times)[i];
        titleArray.add(time + title.attr("title"));
        i++;
    }
```